# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 in android using volley

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-fragments, android-volley

I am making an android application. Basically i am making checkout object. in this object i am sending json object to server. this json object in encoded with utf8.
Encode Object String:

```
EncodedObject: %7B%22AddressID%22%3A107%2C%22CustomerID%22%3A2%2C%22PaymentTypeID%22%3A3%2C%22ListProducts%22%3A%5B%7B%22ProductID%22%3A23%2C%22Price%22%3A0%2C%22Quantity%22%3A0%2C%22ListAttributes%22%3A%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ProductID%22%3A23%2C%22AttributeTypeID%22%3A0%2C%22AttributeID%22%3A0%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22ProductID%22%3A1904%2C%22Price%22%3A16000%2C%22Quantity%22%3A1%2C%22ListAttributes%22%3A%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ProductID%22%3A1904%2C%22AttributeTypeID%22%3A0%2C%22AttributeID%22%3A0%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22ProductID%22%3A23%2C%22Price%22%3A20378%2C%22Quantity%22%3A1%2C%22ListAttributes%22%3A%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ProductID%22%3A23%2C%22AttributeTypeID%22%3A0%2C%22AttributeID%22%3A0%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D
```

here is my volley code:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.orderCheckout,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("Response", response);

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("OrderObject",encodeObject);
            Log.e("order",params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

and here is my encode Object which i am sending to server which is working fine

```
encodeObject = URLEncoder.encode(object.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

[Encode Object Logcat which i am sending to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McNDl.png)

and here is my error [Volley Error Unexpected code 500 snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zknqD.png).
I don't know where i am doing mistake.

Comment: I Don't know the api you're using, but it may be required to send json. Also Encoding an object in "urlencoded utf-8" is no standard either. try using base64.

Comment: hi, Encoded object string cannot be converted to JSONObject why?

Comment: presumably because it is no valid JSON?

Comment: how i can post that string?

Comment: encode to valid JSON

Comment: Please would you explain it how i can encode it?

Comment: No, because I don't know the API and your objects, and will *not* decode your urlsafe decoded object to make valid json. Thats your job! have a look https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp on how to create JSON